# Agregar tarjeta de Bootstrap luego de pulsar un botón en modal

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que quiero es que mediante un modal que tengo, al hacer click en aceptar me agregue a la página una tarjeta de bootstrap5 con los datos que yo ponga en los inputs. ¿Se podrá hacer eso?
He intentado un par de cosas, pero no le hallo solución.

```
<section id="modal" class="modal">
                <div class="contenedor">
                    <figure class="modal-figure">
                      <label for="archivo"></label>
                      <input type="file" id="archivo">
                    </figure>
                    <h2 class="modal-titulo"> Agregar
                        <span> </span>
                    </h2>
                    <br>
                    <p class="modal-p">
                        <label for="titulo">Título</label>
                        <input type="text" id="titulo">
                        <br>
                        <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                        <input type="text" id="descripcion">
                        <br>
                        <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ubicacion">
                        <br>
                        <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                        <input type="text" id="precio">
                        <br>
                    </p> 
                   <br><br>
                    <button href="" id="button" class="btn" onclick="cargarCard()">Aceptar</button>
                </div>
```

```js
function cargarCard(){
    let archivo = document.querySelector(#archivo).value;
    let titulo = document.querySelector(#titulo).value;
    let descripcion = document.querySelector(#descripcion).value;
    let ubicacion = document.querySelector(#ubicacion).value;
    let precio = document.querySelector(#precio).value;
}
```

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con javascript. Pero en tu código no se ve nada de javascript.

Comment: Es que no tengo nada, ni de hecho lo empecé, solo publiqué el modal con el onclick cargarCard... como dije, soy principiante, no se me ha ocurrido mucho para lograrlo...

Comment: Tal vez alguien sea más entendido y me ayude ;)

Comment: Lo siento, tu pregunta carece de un [example] y de un error. Nos estas pidiendo indirectamente que hagamos tu tarea pues tu no has sabido hacer nada, y en este sitio no hacemos código bajo demanda (o no deberiamos), sino que solucionamos errores o a veces orientamos en los comentarios como debe hacerse. Primero pon de tu parte y por favor léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender bien como funciona este sitio. Luego puedes [edit] tu pregunta para adecuarla a las normas que hayas leido para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mejor. Orientación: Busca ejemplos sobre la función innerHTML de js.

Comment: _He intentando un par de cosas_: ¿cuáles cosas? ¿qué errores has tenido? Lee [ask]. Todos fuimos principiantes alguna vez: lo importante es primero **intentarlo**.